# Using the event name in calendar instead of email subject

Tags: java, icalendar, ical4j

I am using ical4j to create a calendar event that's sent via E-Mail. I am giving a different eventName but the event generated in the calendar still has the title of the E-Mail subject. Is it possible to alter this to the summary or descripton given?
Here is my ics-String as it is attached in the MimeMultiBodyPart:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//my ProdId
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20201210T091704Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20201210
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20201211
SUMMARY:MyTitle
UID:20201210T091704Z-uidGen@fe80:0:0:0:dd32:894f:88da:fde6%wlan0
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
CREATED:20201210T091705Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20201210T091705Z
LOCATION:
DESCRIPTION:MyDescription
ORGANIZER;SENT-BY=dontanswer@mail.com:dontanswer@mail.com
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT1H
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```